# iCloud Drive for Windows. When?

Tags: icloud

[iCloud Drive](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/icloud-drive/) is a file hosting service for devices running iOS 8, OS X Yosemite, or Windows 7 or later.

When will we be able to start using iCloud Drive in WIndows PCs? I can't seem t find that info anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess would be Sept 17, date of iOS 8 release; though that is just a guess.
It may be with Yosemite, for which no date has yet been announced, afaik.

"When it's ready!" might be a better answer ;-)

Comment: You were right. iCloud 4.0 is appearing to me in the Apple Software Update

Comment: It is irrelevant now, but it was released earlier then Yosemite was, by about a week maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the windows client is out and works well in my limited experience with it.

Install from http://www.icloud.com/icloudcontrolpanel and the setup guide is at https://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I believe it answers your question directly;

https://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html

Comment: There is no mention of "iCloud Drive" at this link.  This is about iCloud control panel for PC, and has been available for a long time.